# SQL Server 2014 : FileTable trigger on update File_Stream.PathName()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a FileTable `FT` and another table `AT`. In `AT`, I have extended metadata properties of the file in `FT`.

I have tried to create a trigger `ON FT FOR UPDATE` that will update the file path that is in `AT`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[u_filepath] 
ON [FileDB].[dbo].[FT] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    Declare @newpath nvarchar(1000)
    Declare @oldpath nvarchar(1000)

    select @newpath = file_stream.pathname()
    from inserted

    select @oldpath = file_stream.pathname()
    from deleted

    update AT
    set [Path] = @newpath
    where [Path] = @oldpath
GO
```

When I execute the query, it spins. I'm planning on leaving it running overnight just in case it decides to do something.

I want the `Path` column in `AT` to update to the updated `file_stream.PathName()` from `FT`.

Is the trigger logical?

Should I store the file_stream BLOB in my AT Path column instead of the actual path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case.

The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables will each contain 25 rows.

Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?

```
select @newpath = file_stream.pathname()
from inserted
```

It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**.

You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account - use a **set-based** approach to updating your data - not a row-based one - something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[u_filepath] 
ON [FileDB].[dbo].[FT] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- create a CTE to get the primary key, old and new path names
    WITH UpdatedPaths AS
    (
        SELECT
            i.PrimaryKey,
            OldPathName = d.file_stream.pathname(),
            NewPathName = i.file_stream.pathname()
        FROM 
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN
            Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
    )
    -- update the "AT" table where the old and new path names don't match
    UPDATE dbo.AT
    SET [Path] = up.NewPathName
    FROM UpdatedPaths up
    WHERE
       up.OldPathName <> up.NewPathName
       dbo.AT.PrimaryKey = up.PrimaryKey
GO
```

Comment: I would vote up if I had enough rep. Thank you, @marc_s.